# Save and load game minesweeper

Tags: python, tkinter, save

I need help. The task is to add to this game (minesweeper), save the game and download from a file (if there is no file, you need to create one). Also add a check box counter.
[My code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19jLOhbq-J0SOHeXSy59pdLrZYFFkCsS9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This question is far too broad. It's unclear if you don't know how to gather the data, how to format the data, how to open and close files, how to write to files, how to download files, how to add a counter, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pickle for serializing the current instance of the class that is executing the game like:

```
import pickle
def save(self, filename):
    with open(filename, mode) as f:
        pickle.#dump, load(self, f)
```

for mode insert either wb or rb for writing and reading, and then one line below .dump for saving and .load for loading.
Then whenever needed you just call the functions.
I suggest you just read the pickle docs to implement it, so you can acutally understand the logic behind it, instead of blind-copying.

Edit: As Bryan Oakley correctly mentioned, you cant pickle tkinter objects, so for them I would recommend storing the state of the tkinter objects in a dictionary in the class, and pickle that dictionary instead of the tkinter objects.

Comment: You should probably mention that you can't pickle tkinter objects.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt notice that skimming through the code